# Scorm statement if condition

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I have a pretest sco.  I need to make it unlock the entire course if passed or unlock the next lesson if failed.  Is there a way to do something like an if statement in SCORM? Something like if the condition is met then do xyz. and then do another statement that say if a different condition is met then do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the LMS **and** the contents **fully** supports Scorm 2004 >=3rd ed it should be possible using the sequencing and navigation features. Until now I haven't seen a content really using S&N. Most time such features are implement by using the LMS logic.